# Connect Tableau to plain Hbase

Tags: hive, hbase, tableau-api, cdata-drivers

Is there any way to connect Tableau Desktop to plain Apache Hbase or plain Hive ?

I could only find Tableau drivers for Hortonworks/ MapR/ Cloudhera etc.

Answer (score 1):

Install drivers in desktop installed machine.

You can't directly connect to hbase  table via tableau you need to connect to hive table and hive internally mapped to hbase table.
follow links http://thinkonhadoop.blogspot.in/2014/01/access-hbase-table-with-tableau-desktop.html
http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/141px9aqg5/hbase-connectivity-with-tableau

Comment: Do not post links without summarizing their content please.

Answer (score 0):

Our [ODBC Driver for HBase](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/hbase/odbc) will allow you to connect to your HBase data from Tableau. The driver is currently in Beta, so you can download it for free from [here](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/hbase/download/odbc/).

You can read about setting up the connection in our [Knowledge Base](http://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/hbase-odbc-tableau.rst), but in short, you'll need to:

1. Create/configure a DSN from the ODBC Driver (set the server address and port)
2. Click through the Connect to Data options to find Other Database (ODBC) and select the DSN you configured
3. Select CData as the database
4. Enter a Table name (or leave the Table field blank and click search to see a list of Tables).

Once you have access to the tables, you can work with them exactly as you would any other table in Tableau (drag the table to the join area, manipulate Measures and Dimensions to view your data, etc.). If you have any questions, I or our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau internally use SQL to fetch raw data, so theoretically it can support any data source comes with a SQL interface, such as Hive.

Plain Hbase does not provide a SQL interface, so you must add an intermediate layer to translate SQL query into Hbase query. The layer could be an ODBC Driver, or other open source projects such as [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org).