# connect Hbase to Tableau using cdata

Tags: hbase, tableau-api, cdata, cdata-drivers

I am trying to connect `hbase` using `ODBC` Driver but not getting tables in in my tableau screen when I am selecting `cData`. I am using my server `ip` and `hbase` port `16000`.If I am entering table name getting error (An error occurred while communicating with the data source.Unable to connect to the server.Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.)

Reference: [Connect Tableau to plain Hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253141/connect-tableau-to-plain-hbase/37268524#37268524)

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to help with some basic trouble-shooting for our ODBC Driver here, but you may need to contact our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) if this becomes more involved.

Were you able to successfully click the "Test Connection" button that appears in the DSN Configuration Wizard?

Possible solutions:

1. In general, that error indicates that something is preventing our driver from communicating with the server machine. Are there any firewalls or proxies in place? If so, there are connection properties that you can set when you configure the DSN for the driver.
2. Our Driver uses the HBase REST API, so you may need to leave the port property as the default value (`8080`) unless you've specifically configured the REST server to operate using a different port.

Can you review these options to see if they work for you?

If you have any other questions, please let our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) know.